How to show cricket score board in facebook/youtube live stream by using reactNative programming
I create a mobile app who show local crickets score card by programming in react native expo cli.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rafiullahkh.lcsa
Now i want to update the app and want to integrate a score card in facebook/youtube live stream.
If possible then gave me some hints.
I search a lot but does not find any documentation.

Can you provide a screenshot/sketch of what you want ?
